# I cannot change Configuration File (php.ini) Path

Tags: php

I have a problem with locating my php.ini file on my apache server. Server works fine. I am new to this and I have spend hours allready looking for an answer in google and forums.

situation:

I have folders:

> C:\Apache24 
>   C:\php

I have altered the httpd.conf file with the help of internet and added the code like this:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"

PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Still my phpinfo shows "Configuration File (php.ini) Path   `C:\WINDOWS` and no php.ini file is loaded.

Even when I place the php.ini file in the windows folder and change the directory in the httpd.conf file to look in C:\Windows, the php.ini file is not loaded.

With this problem I can not work with phpmyadmin, which is my goal for this moment. It says it cannot find the mysqli extension.

Does anyone provide me with a link to a topic or an answer?

Comment: If you are new, you should try xampp or wamp. These programs provide everything you need out of the box.

Comment: Is it wise to delete the current apache24 program before using wamp is xampp? Which is the best to use?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are editing the good httpd.conf?
Try to add this settings in your httpd.conf:

```
SetEnv PHPRC C:/php
```

But PHPIniDir is supposed to work.

Did you restart your apache server after editing the configuration?

Comment: It’s the correct httpd file because even I change the extension the connection fails entirely. Where do I put this new function? Below what I allready have in httpd file?

Answer (score 0):

I have this now in the httpd.conf file:

```
SetEnv PHPRC C:/php
LoadModule php5_module "C:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Restarted my entire computer, no change.